# Run programs launched from a webpage in wine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gaming, wine

this is my first time on superuser so please go easy on me!

I am steadily trying to distance myself from my ugly grandpa Windows to my hip uncle Ubuntu. In addition to DBA and some hobby development, I do a lot of gaming. Things have been good so far with Wine/Proton/SteamPlay, etc.

Currently I am trying to figure out how to run a certain game from Wine. The game is the Japanese version of SoulWorker, which on Windows is launched by logging into their site (members-soulworker.hangame.co.jp) and then clicking the Launch Game button/link. This pops up a dialogue asking if you want to run the game with their launcher (WeMade Online).

The problem is, I can't figure out how to do this in wine. My wine knowledge is really limited so far, so perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but here is what happens:

In Ubuntu, I downloaded the WeMade Online launcher from their website (by attempting to play the game without it, giving a download link). I then ran:
`$ wine WeMadEOnline.exe` (or whatever the executable is named)
This opened an install prompt, usual Next Next Finish, installed almost instantly cause it's super small.
I tried to launch from Ubuntu, just for kicks, and predictably it still said I didn't have it installed (duh).
Next, tried installing firefox in wine and running that, navigating to the site, logging in, clicking Play, but same thing, it just prompted to install WeMade. So I tried downloading and running it from Firefox, which worked fine, it opened in (presumably) wine with the installer again, Next Next Finish, tried again, still says it's not installed.

I also tried with ie, `$ wine iexplore.exe`. Exact same thing.

Is there some kind of isolation in Wine that prevents my browser from knowing the launcher is installed? Am I going about this completely wrong? I would really appreciate feedback. Thanks!

-- Extra Credit --
[playbutton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Okb6.png)

Browser tools reveal that the button seems to call JavaScript, so extracting and running the link independently won't be straightforward.

Comment: WineHQ have a gold rating for a test taken "Jun 10 2018" for [Soulworker Open Beta](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=36456). Not sure if it's the same game, though...

To get more info, try this out:
`WINEDEBUG=warn+all wine WeMadEOnline.exe`

I'd try out [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) as well.